# How to scroll to the end of a page slowly using selenium so that i can get dynamically loaded content

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a personal project am working on am in a situation where i need to scrape names of items from a dynamic site using selenium.

In order to get all the data you need to scroll to the bottom.

However it gets trickier if you scroll to the bottom to quickly you only get names of items at the bottom. It doesn't matter how long you wait you still get the items on scope.

So i figured i could scroll to the bottom slowly however it doesn't seem to work.

**Here is my demo code to illustrate the problem**

```
url='https://shopzetu.com/search?type=product,article,page&q=dress'
driver.get(url)

#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # this works but you get items at bottom only
#this scrolls slowly to end
driver.execute_script("function pageScroll() {window.scrollBy(0,50);scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',1000);}pageScroll()")
time.sleep(2)
products =driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grid-product__content")
for product in products:
    name=product.find_element_by_class_name("grid-product__title").text
    print(name)
```

Any ideas?

**Extra (imports and configs)**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
 page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
 page.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

**How its applied in this situation**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://shopzetu.com/search?type=product,article,page&q=dress'
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='No thanks']"))).click()
page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
page.send_keys(Keys.END)
products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grid-product__content")
for product in products:
    name = product.find_element_by_class_name("grid-product__title").text
    print(name)
page.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: That doesn't scroll to the end at all

Comment: no i don't close the notification that would take some time...kindly edit your code to full snippet. I do the same when experimenting uncomment the `headless` option

Comment: i see after closing the notification it worked...but only if i close it before the page is fully loaded

Comment: perfect the notification was the one blocking everything

Comment: final code can close the notification auto 

you're welcome good day

Comment: good day to you too... i think you should edit your answer to how it was previously...for another person in future the case of pop up notification wont be inherent to another person.